# constructor missing error although a constructor is implemented

Tags: java, constructor

I have got this constructor undefined error from the following code:

```
package arrayClassObject;

public class Constructor {
    public class Student{
        String name;
        public Student() {

        }
        public Student(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }
        void setName(String name) { // setter
            this.name = name; 
        }   
        public String getName() { // getter
            return name;
        }

        }   
    public static void main(String[] args) {        
        Student s = new Student();
        s.setName("Jack");
        System.out.println(s.getName());
    }

}
```

can anyone explain me why I got such errors? I believe I have done the construction definition in the class Student

```
    The constructor Constructor.Student() is undefined

    at arrayClassObject.Constructor.main(Constructor.java:18)
```

Comment: Just make `Student` static: `public static class Student`

Comment: you probably want to remove the Constructor class, and move the main() method into the Student class.

Comment: @Andy That doesn't explain why though. The OP may need to access instance fields from the enclosing class.

Comment: @WJS Though the error message complains that there is no static inner class named Student in Constructor with a no-arguments constructor.

Comment: @Robert That's because the OP was not instantiating it correctly.  I copied the code exactly, got the same error until I correctly created an instance.  The OP  was trying to instantiate it "as though" it were static.   The compiler is only so smart and makes assumptions.

Comment: @WJS Yes. There are many ways to fix this. Make Student class static, create the new Student from a new Constructor, move Student class to its own file, etc. I deleted my answer because yours sounds better.

Comment: @Robert your right about the multiple solutions.  My assumptions were that the OP wanted a simple inner class but the compiler complained that no `static` inner class existed.  So I demonstrated what to do.  I can see it both ways.

Answer (score 3):

When you have a non-static inner class, you can only make an instance when an instance of the enclosing class exists.  So without changing your `class structures` above, you would need to do the following:

```
Constructor c = new Constructor(); // instance of the enclosing class
Student s = c.new Student();       // special syntax 
s.setName("Jack");
System.out.println(s.getName());
```

Answer (score 0):

You defined `Student` as a nested inner class of the enclosing class `Constructor`. 
Since `Student` is non-static it can only exist with an associated instance of `Constructor`.

See [Nested Classes (The Java™ Tutorials > Learning the Java Language > Classes and Objects)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html) for more information about nested classes.

There are multiple ways to get around this problem.

1. Make `Student` static. That way you don't need an instance of `Constructor` to create a `Student`.
2. Keep `Student` a non-static inner class. Then you first need to construct an instance of `Constructor` for the `Student` to be associated with. (`new Constructor().new Student()`)
3. Move `Student` to its own file. There's probably no need to have `Student` as an inner class. So just make it a regular class.